# Can we program the flow table structure inside an sdn switch in mininet?

Tags: networking, network-programming, sdn, mininet, network-security

I wanted to add some more match fields of my own inside an SDN switch, or some other components apart from the ones already present. Can use any controller for it. Is it possible?